# How to fix mailchimp full popup view in mobile

Tags: javascript, wordpress, popup, mailchimp, mobile-website

I have added to mailchimp to my website. Everything works fine in desktop . 
When It comes to mobile  instead of popping up on middle . It is resized without image at top

I want it to popup with full size in middle  is there any code to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Iframes than you can add

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  Iframes {
    height : 25%;
    width  : 25%;
  }
}
```